# MongoDB aggregate lookup not working for post comments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lookup, aggregation

I have two collections where need to lookup on aggregate.That's pretty straightforward where posts need to lookup comments on listing.

Here I defined `Content` schema -

```
const ContentSchema = new Schema({
    .........
    linkName: {
        type: String,

    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true 
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Content', ContentSchema);
```

Comment schema `contentComment` -

```
const contentCommentSchema = new Schema({
    ........
    content: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Content'
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('contentComment', contentCommentSchema);
```

Here is the query where I am trying to list posts(`Content` schema) with corresponding comments from `contentComment` -

```
const contentPromise = Content.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'contentComments',
            let: { contentId: '$_id' },
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: [ '$content', '$$contentId' ]
                    }
                } 
            }],
            as: 'nbComments'
        }
        .......
    }
]);
```

Also I tried with following `$lookup` -

```
const contentPromise = Content.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "contentComments",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "content",
            as: "nbComments"
        }
        .......
    }
];
```

But every time it returns empty array for `comments`.

Here are two screenshots of **MongoDB Compass** for `contents` -

[image: content documents]

and `contentComments` -

[image: content comments documents]

I can't figure out the issue for returning empty error for `nbComments` even though there are sufficient comments for a specific post/content. Here is a screenshot -

[image: empty result for nbComments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from is using **plurals lowercase collection name**, as you use in mongo terminal.

So you have to use contentcomments and not contentComments

You can either use contentComment.collection.name

Example:

```
const AwesomeNameSchema = new Schema({
=   
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('AwesomeName', AwesomeNameSchema);
```

In mongo terminal

```
db.AwesomeName.count(); // return 0, not working
db.AwesomeNames.count(); // return 0, not working
db.awesomename.count(); // return 0, not working

db.awesomenames.count(); // return X, working solution
```

In mongoose lookup

```
var AwesomeName = require("./models/AwesomeName.js");
var ParentAwesomeName = require("./models/ParentAwesomeName.js");

// not working
ParentAwesomeName.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "AwesomeNames",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "awesome_name",
            as: "awesome"
        }
        .......
    }
]; 

// working
ParentAwesomeName.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "awesomenames",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "awesome_name",
            as: "awesome"
        }
        .......
    }
]; 

// working
ParentAwesomeName.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: AwesomeName.collection.name,
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "awesome_name",
            as: "awesome"
        }
        .......
    }
];
```

Comment: it is already object id in collection look at the screenshots.

Comment: sorry answering too fast :)

Comment: when we don't specify collection name mongoose will create from model name 1) from `Content` to `contents` and 2) from `contentComment` to `contentComments`.

Comment: i'm not using any collection name declaration in my node app using mongoose, but iknow that trying to use the collection name not in lowercase in mongo shell OR in aggregate lookup provide empty result

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-pluralize
https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongoose-legacy-pluralize/blob/master/index.js